# What does selector with brackets match? :not(a)[routerLink]

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

This is a selector used to match `routerLink` directive.

I know that `:not(a)` matches any element which is not an `a` element, but what does `[routerLink]` part mean?

Comment: what you are trying to do ? and what you tried so far ?

Comment: @anshuVersatile: He's trying to understand what the selector means.

Comment: Haven't you answered yourself in your opening statement?

Comment: @BoltClock, I think I've twisted myself into a knot. Would these be the same: `:not(a)[routerLink]` vs `:not(a[routerLink])`?

Comment: @Michael_B: No. `:not(a)[routerLink])` will never match `a` elements, `:not(a[routerLink])` will match `a` elements that don't have the attribute (in the selectors-4 profile). If the asker is stating that `:not(a)[routerLink]` *is* matching a specific `a` element, then something's amiss.

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov did you ever figure out why this works for angular's RouterLink class? seems to me it would prevent matching precisely what it ought to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code -- `:not(a)[routerLink]` -- you're saying: *select all elements, except anchors, that contain the `routerLink` attribute*.

The brackets (`[]`) represent an attribute selector.

```
<div class="somevalue">
```

You can target the element above like this:

```
[class] { background-color: red; }
```

It matches all elements with a `class` attribute.

Have a look at this table for more details:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

---

With thanks to @BoltClock for distinguishing between two selectors that look alike, but are different:

- `:not(a)[routerLink])` will never match `a` elements
- `:not(a[routerLink])` will match `a` elements that don't have the attribute. (Note that compound selectors in the `:not()` pseudo-class are available as of Selectors 4.)

Comment: So, in my example, `:not(a)[routerLink]` matches any element where `routerElement` present (except a element). It makes sense, but then why when I put `routerLink` directive on `a` element directive still works(meaning Angular matches it anyway)

Comment: `:not(a)[routerLink]`  is an actual selector used in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts

Comment: thank you good sir! I guess it has to do with how Angular works internally.

Comment: What if your interpolating the routerLink value like `[routerLink]="/somePath"` how do you select the attribute when it's wrapped in `[]`?  Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Figured it out you need to use `ng-reflect-router-link` instead of routerLink so it would look like: `:not(a)[ng-reflect-router-link]`